# How does priority order effect a chain of add_action's and do_action's in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have two "chains" of actions in WordPress (`add_action`'s and `do_action`'s linked together) and I need all of the first chain to complete before starting the second chain.

Using `priority` order I can trigger the start of each chain one after the other, but I am worried that a large loop in the middle of the first chain will still be running when the second chain starts.

**EXAMPLE:**

Since the `first_chain_first_loop` action has a priority of `10`, and `second_chain_first_loop` action has a priority of `11`, will the entire first chain of actions (`first_chain_first_loop` + `first_chain_second_loop`) be processed before `second_chain_first_loop` starts?

Or does `second_chain_first_loop` start immediately after `first_chain_first_loop` is complete? And if this is the case, how can I ensure the second chain will wait for the first chain to complete (including the large loop) before triggering the second chain.

```
//First chain of actions - Has early priority but a large loop in the middle
add_action( 'init', 'first_chain_first_loop', 10 );
function first_chain_first_loop() {
    for ( $i=0; $i < 10; ++$i ) {
        do_action( 'first_chain_second_loop_action', $i );
    }
}
add_action( 'first_chain_second_loop_action', 'first_chain_second_loop', 10, 1 );
function first_chain_second_loop( $i ) {
    for ( $i=0; $i < 1000000000; ++$i ) {
        do_action( 'first_chain_logic_function_action', $i );
    }
}
add_action( 'first_chain_logic_function_action', 'first_chain_logic_function', 10, 1 );
function first_chain_logic_function( $i ) {
    //Do stuff here
}


//Second chain of actions  - Has later priority
add_action( 'init', 'second_chain_first_loop', 11 );
function second_chain_first_loop() {
    for ( $i=0; $i < 10; ++$i ) {
        do_action( 'second_chain_second_loop_action',  $i );
    }
}
add_action( 'second_chain_second_loop_action', 'second_chain_second_loop', 10, 1 );
function second_chain_second_loop( $i ) {
    for ( $i=0; $i < 10; ++$i ) {
        do_action( 'second_chain_logic_function_action', $i );
    }
}
add_action( 'second_chain_logic_function_action', 'second_chain_logic_function', 10, 1 );
function second_chain_logic_function( $i ) {
    //Do stuff here
}
```